# Errors Integrating SED into a Bash Loop

Tags: bash, sed, cat

I'm having an issue with a bash script I've written. The command works until the SED, and I'm not really sure what I've done incorrectly. HAL is the variable in the text file that I'm trying to replace. Any ideas?

```
 for i in $( cat LIST.txt) do 
 sed s/HAL/i/ <~/test/template.txt > new$i.txt
 done
```

The error given is "syntax error near unexpected token sed" it then gives the sed line.

Comment: `for i in $(cat foo.txt)` is definitely the wrong way to iterate over lines in a file, to start. See BashFAQ #001: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: ...that said, you aren't saying *how* it fails when it reaches the `sed` expression, so how are we supposed to know what needs to be fixed?

Comment: ...also, quote your expansions: `>"new$i.txt"` will succeed in places where `>new$i.txt` fails.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 is also relevant.

Comment: ...anyhow -- as it is, this question can't be answered, because it doesn't state a specific error, as opposed to "an issue" and "works until".

Comment: Your `sed` invocation as written simply replaces any occurrences of "HAL" with "i". Perhaps you meant `sed -e "s/HAL/${i}/"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the semi-colon between the `for` part and the `do`.

```
for i in $(cat LIST.txt); do 
    sed s/HAL/i/ <~/test/template.txt > new$i.txt
done
```

This is probably better rewritten as (assuming there's one word per line in `LIST.txt`:

```
while read i; do
    # Are you sure you don't want to substitute with the variable (`$i`
    # in this case) instead of "i" in the line below?
    sed s/HAL/i/ < ~/test/template.txt > new$i.txt
done < LIST.txt
```

You might want your `sed` line to be like below if you want to substitute with `$i`:

```
sed "s/HAL/$i/" < ~/test/template.txt > new$i.txt
```